# Python3: Split multiple variables dynamically

Tags: python, network-programming

I'm trying to split multiple variables that were dynamically created off a for loop and then delete everything after the first space.

Minor back story: I'm using paramiko to SSH to a network switch to pull VLAN information. Trying to create a new variable for each VLAN name and then present all variables back into a list for the user to select from.

```
#VLANLines## were split from VLANList off \r\n. Variables created form a for loop
VLANLine1 = 'GGGGGGGGG      5                                        5/7'
VLANLine2 = 'HHHH           66                                       22/23'
VLANLine3 = 'SSSSSSS        33                                       3/4'

#HHHH and SSSSSS are random names I put in place for this question. This is the data I need to keep.

#Length of VLANList = 14 in this demo
i = 0
while i < len(VLANList):
    VLANLine[i].split(" ")
    del VLAN[i][1:]
```

Error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 2, in <module>
    VLANLine[i].split(" ")
IndexError: string index out of range
```

How can I dynamically split 'VLANLine##' and then delete out everything after the space? I may be going at this all wrong too. I just started working with python a few weeks ago.

Comment: You don't increase `i` in your while loop...

Comment: Even with i = i + 1 it still fails on the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for you.

```
VLAN_clean = [v[0:v.find(' ')] for v in VLANList if v.find(' ') != -1]
```

Comment: Wow. That actually worked out very well! Could you give me some details in how that is working properly?

Comment: `for v in VLANList if v.find(' ') != -1` is iterating through your VLANList and testing each item for a space somewhere within the string. `v.find(' ')` will return -1 if it doesn't find what you're looking and will return the index location of the first instance of (in this case) a space if it does find something.

If the list element does have a space then `v[0:v.find(' ')]` will slice and return the string from the `0` index to before the first space.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`str.split` does what you need cleanly:

```
VLANList = [
        'GGGGGGGGG      5                                        5/7',
        'HHHH           66                                       22/23',
        'SSSSSSS        33                                       3/4',
    ]
VLAN_Clean = [v.split()[0] for v in VLANList]
print(VLAN_Clean)
```

Output:

```
['GGGGGGGGG', 'HHHH', 'SSSSSSS']
```

`split` will split each string at the first space character, returning a tuple of values. If there is no blank, it will simply return a tuple of length 1 containing the entire string. So, running split on each item, then selecting the first item from the resulting tuple gives you the right thing.